# PHP, adding time to date();?

Tags: php

I have used this to get the server date,

```
$yd = getdate();

echo $yd['year'];
echo $yd['mon'];
echo $yd['mday'];
```

...but how do I add something to it. For example, I want to know what date it will be in 7 days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+7 days"));
```

Comment: THANKS! It works. And another quick question, can I also compare them?
such as if ( date("Y-m-d") > 21-12-2010 ) {} ? to know if this date has already passed or not.

Comment: You can compare them, but make sure the format is the same - unlike in your example. Do it like `date("Y-m-d") > "2010-12-14"`.

Comment: I usually force them both to be unix timestamp so my comparison would be strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) > strtotime("2010-12-24")

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)